# How to create a login page in django 1.9.2

Tags: python, django

Can anyone tell me how to create a login app in django 1.9.2 most of the tutorials and documentation are not very specific about creating a login form.

Comment: have you tried googling for this? here's a couple results: http://solutoire.com/2009/02/26/django-series-1-a-custom-login-page/ 
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html
from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/

Comment: This is [right in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)...

Answer (score 0):

This is great tutorial of django you need create model and insert username and password with hash ,check authenticate use custom login required,

http://solutoire.com/2009/02/26/django-series-1-a-custom-login-page/